# Angular - change only one element of ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have the following `angular` template where I display a list of items.

```
<div *ngFor="let i of immobili | async">
    <div [ngSwitch]="edit" (update)="editUpdate($event)">
      <immobile-detail (onEdit)="isEdit($event, i)" *ngSwitchCase="false" [immobile]="i" [idR]="idRichiesta"></immobile-detail>
      <immobile-form (onEdit)="isEdit($event, i)" *ngSwitchCase="true" [immobile]="i" [idR]="idRichiesta"></immobile-form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I display two different components wheter if an event is happening on an item or not. The problem is that the component changes for every item and not only for the one I selected. Is there a way to switch the component only for the item I registered the event on? Thanks in advance for the hints.

**Edit**
I'll explain better.
I have a situation like this:

```
<parent>
  <div *ngFor="let i of immobili | async">
    <child1></child1>
    <child2></child2>
  </div>
</parent>
```

So for each object in my list I can display component `child1` or `child2` based on a choiche made inside one of the two children view. I managed to make the children to communicate with parent using `@Output` directive, and this works fine. The problem is that when I switch between the two children the components of ALL the objects in my list change too. I think that this happens because the change is made at parent level. Instead I want to change only the component referred to the element where I made the choice, maybe passing the object index or something.
FYI in the end I solved my problem because due to other reasons I used a different approach (only one component), but I'd really like to know how this can be done. Thanks.